# Disable "Open Document" in Oracle Attachments (Oracle Applications)

Tags: oracle, attachment, oracleapplications

Up to recently I had disabled Attachments for a responsibility.

I have now been asked to activate them (fine) but only allow for the agent to upload attachments and not view them.

The (what I thought would be) simplest way of doing this was to remove the "Open Document" button in the Attachments window but can not find it in any menu.

Is this even possible? I only have access to Oracle Applications so can not query the backend directly.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set FND Diagnostics profile to Yes for your user.

Navigate to your screen and then Help > Diagnostics > Properties > Item

You will be able to find the internal name of the button.  You can then use Forms personalisation to remove it.

Answer (score 0):

You can disable or hide that button through form personalisation as we can do for any field in any forms.